# undefined variable in the view CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Users.php Controller

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{
  public function userList(){
    $data['results'] = $this->user_model->get_users();
    $this->load->view('users_view',$data);
  }
}
```

user_model.php Model

```
class User_model extends CI_Model{
  public function get_users()  
  {  
    $query = $this->db->get('users');  
    return $query->result();  
  }
}
```

users_view.php View

```
foreach ($results as $list) {
  echo $list->id;
}
```

main.php View

```
$this->load->view('users_view');
```

When i view http://localhost:81/rokki/users/userlist the id is displayed. But, when i view in http://localhost:81/rokki/home thru the main.php I'm getting errors as below :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: results
>
> Filename: views/users_view.php
>
> Line Number: 41
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\rokki\application\views\users_view.php Line: 41
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\rokki\application\views\layouts\main.php Line:
>   20 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\rokki\application\controllers\Home.php Line: 7
>   Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\rokki\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

I'm newbie to the CI. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck with any of the answers

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a controller for `home` like you do for `users`? Looking at your call stack it appears you have one so I assume it's something like this if it isn't already.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $data['results'] = $this->user_model->get_users();
        $this->load->view('main',$data);
   }
}
```

Then in your main.php passing the results data to the view_users view like so.

```
$this->load->view('view_users', $results);
```

Comment: Because is $data you still would need to do `$this->load->view('view_users', $data);` and not `$this->load->view('view_users', $results);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

Because your function userList

`http://localhost:81/rokki/users/userList`

Users.php

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{


   public function userList(){
     $this->load->model('user_model');
     $data['results'] = $this->user_model->get_users();
     $this->load->view('users_view',$data);
   }
}
```

User_model.php

```
class User_model extends CI_Model{
  public function get_users()  
  {  
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    // Change the result to array  
    return $query->result_array();  
  }
}
```

On the view

```
foreach ($results as $list) {
  echo $list['id'];
}
```